# How to start SSH daemon on boot on Linux Mint Debian v2

Tags: ssh, services, sshd, daemon

I'm using Linux Mint Debian v2, 64-bit.

I noticed recently that my ssh daemon does not start automatically on boot. It used to. I'm not sure if it had to do with my UFW configuration or sshd_config configurations, but, it doesn't start now unless I put:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

I've searched the net and I could find some solutions such as:

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults
```

and creating an sshd file in `/etc/init.d`, but, they didn't work.

I've tried purging ssh and openssh-server and re-installing. But, that didn't have any effect. It started automatically after re-installing, but, once I rebooted and checked for the ssh daemon, it wouldn't show up.

Any suggestions on how I can get it to start on boot?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have installed `openssh-server` , check for `sshd` startup symbolic links at `/etc/rc{2,3,4,5}` directories , run `ls -l /etc/rc?.d/*ssh`
if no startup links there , create them by running:

`sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults`

and reboot.

If problem not solved yet, you may try it by placing `service ssh start` (before the "exit 0" line)
at `/etc/rc.local` file and reboot again.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is simple with systemctl

~ $ **sudo systemctl enable ssh.service**
synchronizing state of ssh.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ssh
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service → /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service.

Either reboot to activate or use

~ $ **sudo systemctl start ssh.service**

Comment: Is this all to do: `sudo systemctl enable ssh.service` and then reboot? `sysv` seems to be the old system before `systemd`.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add this line in the bottom:

```
@reboot sleep 15 && /bin/systemctl restart sshd
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. As I posted in my other post:
[Is there a specific SSH boot log?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/is-there-a-specific-ssh-boot-log/211192#211192)

In my auth.log file, it wasn't binding to the IP address I put in for the ListenAddress parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. After I changed it back to 0.0.0.0, it starts up now. Don't quite understand, I thought I could put the IP address of my computer?

And I don't understand why it doesn't start at boot, yet, manually, it can start.

Comment: ListenAddress 0.0.0.0 works for me. :D Thanks.

Comment: I also am using a ListenAddress in my sshd_config file other than 0.0.0.0. None of the solutions on this page worked except changing the ListenAddress back to 0.0.0.0. Does anyone have any REAL solutions or answers as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a raspberry, my quick and dirty solution was update-rc.d disable abd I put service ssh start in my rc.local.

maybe in your case a service ssh enable will help,...