# Is there a specific SSH boot log?

Tags: ssh, startup, init.d

My sshd won't start at bootup. I have to type it in manually (`sudo service ssh start`).

I've posted a question on how to start ssh at bootup ([How to start SSH daemon on boot on Linux Mint Debian v2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210710/)), but, everything I've tried has not worked.

I checked /var/log/boot.log, it actually says:

> [ ok ] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd

However, when I type `ps -A | grep ssh`, sshd does not show up. If I start it manually (`sudo service ssh start`), it does show up. Is there a specific log for SSH that I can check?

I'm using LMDE v2, 64-bit, Mate.

Comment: What distro and version are you using, debian? did you try chkconfig?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the logs?

Comment: lcd047: Yes, I updated my question.

Comment: In `systemd` based systems, it's possible that only a socket is opened and the daemon loads on demand, when a request comes. I hope this is relevant.

Comment: orion: Well, I've tried to ssh into my computer even though sshd doesn't show up with `ps -A`. I can't login. Once I manually start it, I can login. So, I sort of understand what you're saying, but, I think based on this scenario, I would say the daemon is not loading when the request comes in, if I'm interpreting your point correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In my auth.log file, it wasn't binding to the IP address I put in for the ListenAddress parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. After I changed it back to 0.0.0.0, it starts up now. Don't quite understand, I thought I could put the IP address of my computer?

And I don't understand why it doesn't start at boot, yet, manually, it can start.

Comment: Suspect `sshd` is starting before your specific ip address has been assigned. So it's not available when `sshd` tries to bind with the `Listen` directive